# COUNTIFS function with text that contains?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[Example of the desired outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g517q.png)

I'm hoping to count the number of values each day that match a list, and group them by category in the list. See the image for an example - the categories are Florida and Georgia.

What has made this difficult for me is that many cells are not an exact match to the list. They all contain the full value that the list has, but often additional text before or after.

I was hoping to use a formula something like below, but was never able to get the expected values.

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(E2:E5,"*"&A1:A6&"*",B1:B6,"Florida"))`

See the image for the desired outcome.

Thank you for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Update: Found myself an answer! Posting here in case anyone is curious. The first cell is below. I dragged that across, then just changed Florida to Georgia for the second row.

`=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(E$2:E$5,"*"&FILTER($A$1:$B$6,$B$1:$B$6="Florida")&"*"))`

Comment: YES! You can also use SUM instead of SUMPRODUCT. Plus, if you entered just "Florida" and "Georgia" in cells D9 and D10, you could use $D9 instead of "Florida" to copy the formula down and across.